# Facebook API OAuthException: (#2) Failed to create notification

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having and issue sending app notifications using the Facebook API.

I have a script that sends notifications to users if their invitation is accepted. Almost all of the tested notifications are successful, but when someone tries to send an notification to me (developer of the app), I get an error. But only when the Facebook app is `not` in development mode and when I remove myself as developer/tester of the app.
The problem is that I don't know if other users will have this error, because right now, as far as I know, only I get this error.
I also couldn't find any explanations about the error message.

Please help.

This is the PHP code that sends the notification

```
try {
    $response = $facebook->api( '/'.$userID.'/notifications', 'POST', array(
        'template' => $messageText,
        'href' => $link,
        'access_token' => $app_access_token
    ));  

} catch (Exception $e) {`
    print_r($e);
}
```

This is the exception that gets thrown:

```
FacebookApiException Object
(
    [result:protected] => Array
        (
            [error] => Array
                (
                    [message] => (#2) Failed to create notification
                    [type] => OAuthException
                    [is_transient] => 1
                    [code] => 2
                )

    )

[message:protected] => (#2) Failed to create notification
[string:Exception:private] => 
[code:protected] => 0
[file:protected] => /[PRIVATE]/facebook-php-sdk/src/base_facebook.php
[line:protected] => 1340
[trace:Exception:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [file] => /[PRIVATE]/facebook-php-sdk/src/base_facebook.php
                [line] => 911
                [function] => throwAPIException
                [class] => BaseFacebook
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [error] => Array
                                    (
                                        [message] => (#2) Failed to create notification
                                        [type] => OAuthException
                                        [is_transient] => 1
                                        [code] => 2
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [function] => _graph
                [class] => BaseFacebook
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => /[myID]/notifications
                        [1] => POST
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [template] => [PRIVATE]
                                [href] => [PRIVATE]
                                [access_token] => [PRIVATE]
                            )

                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [file] => /[PRIVATE]/facebook-php-sdk/src/base_facebook.php
                [line] => 687
                [function] => call_user_func_array
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Facebook Object
                                    (
                                        [sharedSessionID:protected] => 
                                        [appId:protected] => [PRIVATE]
                                        [appSecret:protected] => [PRIVATE]
                                        [user:protected] => 0
                                        [signedRequest:protected] => 
                                        [state:protected] => 
                                        [accessToken:protected] => [PRIVATE]
                                        [fileUploadSupport:protected] => 
                                        [trustForwarded:protected] => 
                                        [allowSignedRequest:protected] => 
                                    )

                                [1] => _graph
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => /[myID]/notifications
                                [1] => POST
                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [template] => [PRIVATE]
                                        [href] => [PRIVATE]
                                        [access_token] => [PRIVATE]
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [file] => /[PRIVATE]
                [line] => 22
                [function] => api
                [class] => BaseFacebook
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => /[myID]/notifications
                        [1] => POST
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [template] => [PRIVATE]
                                [href] => [PRIVATE]
                                [access_token] => [PRIVATE]
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[previous:Exception:private] => 
)
```